# Connecting to PPPoE server through wireless switch

Tags: wifi, pppoe

I have the following set up:

```
D-Link DSR-250N Wireless N Gigabit VPN Router (all machines connected to LAN ports, including server)

Server (CentOS 5)  
  -eth0: connected to LAN port on router
  -eth1: connected to local network
```

The server is running a PPPoE server (specifically, rp-pppoe). I also have iptables forwarding eth1 to eth0.

I have a computer running Windows XP connected to the router (LAN) as well. I've created a PPPoE connection on this computer, and once it authenticates with the PPPoE server it can access the network (the network connected to eth1 on the server). This works perfectly.

The issue is, when I connect a computer wirelessly to the switch instead of using a cable, the PPPoE connection doesn't authenticate with the server. On the server I can see that it assigns the wireless computer an IP address (it starts a pppd process with the wireless computers MAC address and an IP), but on the wireless computer the authentication eventually times out. On the server, I see the following in syslog:

```
pppoe-server[5643]: Session 13 created for client xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx (192.168.1.13) on eth0 using Service-Name 'PPPoE'  
pppd[5643]: pppd 2.4.5 started by root, uid 0  
pppd[5643]: Using interface ppp0  
pppd[5643]: Connect: ppp0 <--> /dev/pts/1  
pppd[5643]: LCP: timeout sending Config-Requests  
pppd[5643]: Connection terminated.  
pppoe[5644]: read (asyncReadFromPPP): Session 13: Input/output error
pppd[5643]: Exit.
pppoe-server[4977]: Session 13 closed for client xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx (192.168.1.13) on eth0
pppoe-server[4977]: Sent PADT
pppoe-server[4977]: PADT for session 13 received from xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx; should be from 00:00:00:00:00:00
```

With the exact same laptop, but using a wired connection, I see something like this:

```
pppd[4075]: pppd 2.4.5 started by root, uid 0  
pppd[4075]: Using interface ppp0  
pppd[4075]: Connect: ppp0 <--> /dev/pts/1  
pppd[4075]: local  IP address 10.0.0.1  
pppd[4075]: remote IP address 10.67.15.1
```

So using a wireless connection, the computer can see the PPPoE server and the server responds and even assigns the computer an IP address, but the authentication eventually times out and the computer can't access the network, and the pppd process on the server goes away.

With a wired connection using the same computer the authentication works and the computer can access the network.

Any ideas?

Comment: what is the exact dlink model?

Comment: It's a DLink DSR-250N. I guess I should of called it a router instead of a switch. D-Link's name for it is "Wireless N Gigabit VPN Router".

Comment: It's possible that your "wireless switch" (it's a router exactly) is masking your mac address - this won't work. You will have to create a bridge connection so the mac addressess could flow through it freely.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have a wireless bridge at the moment, but I've found some more syslog messages to do with the wireless connection issue so I've added them above (the ones regarding "session 13").